# Matching SessionId from SessionManagement Class to SessionKey from LogoutEventStream

Tags: loginflow, session-id, logout, sessionstorage

I'm trying to execute some Apex in a `LogoutEventStream` trigger that checks against the user's sessionId (`SessionManagement.getCurrentSession().get('SessionId')`, however the SessionKey field provided by the LogoutEventStream does not match. Is there an encoding that is being used to transform it? Is there another way to match with the user's sessionId during a logoutevent?

Note, I unsuccessfuly attempted to use getCurrentSession in the Apex --> "System.UnexpectedException: Current session unavailable". I assume it failed because in the context of a LogoutEventTrigger, the session no longer exists. I also attempted to fire the trigger before insert but this is not supported for platform events.

Comment: The Platform Event runs as a separate transaction and as `Automated Process` user so it makes sense there is no match between value in the PE and the current trigger user's session

Comment: @cropredy I'm using the logouteventstream to define the event of "a session ended". Then, I want to know *which* session ended, so I can match it up to the login flow that I executed previously. 

What I was hoping for is the following: 
(Event published) "LogoutEventStream published" --> (Event handled) "A session ended" --> (My code) "Which session ended?" --> Get Session from MySessions where SessionId = thisLogoutEvent.SessionKey

So, aside from the logouteventstream, is there a way to check an ended session against existing sessions?

Answer (score 1):

The Platform Event runs as a separate transaction and as `Automated Process` user so it makes sense there is no match between value in the PE and the current trigger user's session

So, this is how I would approach it if you want to correlate logins to logouts:

You need to query two big objects

```
SELECT LoginKey FROM LogoutEvent
```

and

```
SELECT LoginKey FROM LoginEvent
```

From the [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/sforce_api_objects_loginevent.htm?q=loginEvent)

> **LoginKey**
>
> Type: string
>
> Properties: Nillable
>
> Description: The string that ties together all events in a given user’s login session. The session starts with a login event and ends with either a logout event or the user session expiring. This field is available in API version 46.0 and later. For example, lUqjLPQTWRdvRG4.

The `SessionKey` field is null on the LoginEvent object (which is auto-populated by the `LoginEventStream` event.  The `LogoutEvent` big object is auto-created by the `LogoutEventStream` event. Note that user session expiry does not create a `LogoutEventStream` unless `Force logout on session timeout` is enabled (hat tip to @identigral for this)

Comment: Session timeout should trigger a logout event if `Force logout on session timeout` is enabled. As of this writing, there's a [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001nSIzQAM) with this feature.