# Event Log - SESSION_KEY is null

Tags: eventlogfile, event-monitoring

It seems the LOGIN_KEY and SESSION_KEY are the fields used to tie the events together for a particular user session

However it is still a bit unclear what the relationship between those are
If the same user logs in multiple times (for example UI and API) without logging out in between will it have the same LOGIN_KEY with different SESSION_KEYs ?
I guess if the user logs out then a new LOGIN_KEY is generated (and new SESSION_KEY)

Does any know why the SESSION_KEY field is null in many cases, it seems to be null in Login event but also in ApexTrigger event type (and many other events). How should this be interpreted ?
There are also cases where LOGIN_KEY is populated but not the SESSION_KEY and also cases where both is null

There is an old article on the web, https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2017/two-new-keys-unlock-users-event-data but it does not answer all the questions

Comment: The article you linked explains it well. Why it's blank on a Login Event: see [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_login.htm). For a trigger, it might be blank if there's no UI event but this is speculation on our part. Open a support case.

Comment: [related question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/391714/2602)

Comment: It's a bit strange that the column user id is populated with a known user but the session key and sometimes also the login key is empty. This can be seen in many events like ApexExecution and ApexTrigger. In my mind the user should always have a corresponding session. Need to create a support case and hopefully get some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I created ticket to Salesforce support and they responded that it's a bug and will be fixed in upcoming release.

> Please be informed that the issue you reported to us is identified as
> a Bug by our R&D team and have scheduled a Bug fix in the upcoming
> release

Comment: when/if they give you a Known Issue link, please use [edit] to amend this answer. Thanks for following up with support